# not able to start angular2 app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am not able to start my angular-2 app,

[it showing after running ng serve from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flref.png)

I have followed this official link,

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Is there any pre configuration needed to use this tutorial although I have installed node v6.9.1 and npm 3.10.8

my console showing these lines

```
69% building modules 699/700 modules 1 active ...\@angular\common\src\facade\er
Hash: 5ea61db5c1181d6b96be
Time: 11129ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.map (polyfills) 222 kB {4} [i
nitial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.map (main) 3.98 kB {3} [initial] [rende
red]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.map (styles) 10 kB {4} [initial] [r
endered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.map (vendor) 2.62 MB [initial] [ren
dered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rende
red]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: what command did you use to start it ?

Comment: ng serve and ng start also tried

Comment: could you add error stack traces in console ?

Comment: Post errors you get from console.

Comment: My console showing these lines :

chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rende
red]
webpack: Compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

"webpack: Compiled successfully." is what your console is supposed to show when webpack is working properly.

Try to view your running app at http://localhost:4200/